# Flutter DropDownMenu: Initialize default value async

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, dart, stateful

we have a flutter-project running and want to include a stateful widget with a dropdownmenu. We use SQflite as our database.

We have a list of profiles in our database and with the dropdown we want to select one of the profiles. This works fine.

### The Problem:

We save the ID of the last profile selected in with SharedPreferences. Initially we want to have the profile with the last selected id (which we load from SharedPreferences) as the default value.

Our Dropdown-Menu inside a future-builder (of the list `profilesFuture` with type `Future<List<Profile>>`):

```
return new Container(
    child: DropdownButton<Profile>(
        items: snapshot.data.map((Profile item) {
            return DropdownMenuItem<Profile>(
                value: item,
                child: Text(item.caption + " (" + item.serverAddress + ")")
            );
        }).cast<DropdownMenuItem<Profile>>().toList(),
        onChanged: (Profile newSelectedProfile) {
            setState(() {
                selectedProfile = newSelectedProfile;
                PreferencesService.setLastProfileId(newSelectedProfile.id);
            });
        },
        value: selectedProfile,
    )
);
```

We initialize our state like this:

```
Future profilesFuture;
Profile selectedProfile;
Future prefService;
int lastProfileId;

@override
void initState() {
    profilesFuture = DatabaseService.db.getProfiles();

    super.initState();
    _getLastProfileId().then((value) => _getSelectedProfile(value));
}

Future<Profile> _getSelectedProfile(int id) async {
    Profile profile = await DatabaseService.db.getProfileById(id);
    setState(() {
      selectedProfile = profile;
    });
    return profile;
}

Future<int> _getLastProfileId() async {
    int profileId = await PreferencesService.getLastProfileId();
    setState(() {
      lastProfileId = profileId;
    });
    return profileId;
}
```

### The Error

```
either zero or 2 or more dropdownmenuitems were detected with the same value. Assertion failed. There should be exactly one item with DropDownMenus value.
```

Further information: https://github.com/glutter-dev-team/glutter/blob/feature/profile-selector/lib/widgets/profile_selector.dart

### The Question

Whats wrong with it? How to correctly initialize a DropDownMenu with async values. The Problem definitely is caused by the default value. Without initializing the value-parameter it works fine, but the initial state is not correct.

All we have to do is:

1. Load the lastSelectedProfileId from SharedPreferences (async)
2. Load the selectedProfile from the database-layer (async)
3. Load the list of all profiles from the database-layer (async)
4. Set the selectedProfile as default value and the list as dropdownmenu-items

Comment: We use a ```FutureBuilder``` to the ```profilesFuture``` (the list) around this like mentioned above.

Comment: your error comes from https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/2783f8e2e1/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/dropdown.dart#L836 - most likely you dont have == operator and/or hashCode methods overriden in your `Profile` class

Comment: Should we override this? Because of what? And with what?

Comment: because of [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/2783f8e2e1/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/dropdown.dart#L836) assert - there is a check: `items.where((DropdownMenuItem<T> item) {
return item.value == value;
}).length == 1`

Comment: Okay, we´ve checked that. It solved our problem. Do you want to post this as an answer or should i do this by reference your comment?

Comment: i am not sure if hashCode needs to be overriden too in this particular case - but it is always a good practice to override both

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224022/discussion-between-mrzjkl-and-pskink).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referring to [@pskink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2252830/pskink) this is the solution which solved our issue:

We have overridden the default `==` Operation in our Datamodel `Profile`.

```
bool operator == (dynamic other) =>
    other != null && other is Profile && this.id == other.id;

@override
int get hashCode => super.hashCode;
```

Comment: hmmm, this `hashCode` does nothing - better override it with a `id.hashCode`

Comment: Done :) Works fine too. Thank you <3

Answer (score 0):

You should check **value** must in **items.value**. What you are required to check in dropdown

```
    List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> _bankAccountType = [
    DropdownMenuItem(child: Text("--"), value: "--"),
    DropdownMenuItem(child: Text("Checking"), value: "Checking"),
    DropdownMenuItem(child: Text("Savings"), value: "Savings"),
  ];

DropdownButton<String>(
                      items: _bankAccountType,
                      iconSize: 0.0,
                      value: _bankAccountTypeValue,
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        setState(() {
                          _bankAccountTypeValue = value;
                        });
                        _checkBankAccountFormStatus();
                      }
                  ),
```

this will help you to fix the issue.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. But what i look for is your fruitType[0]. We have to pass _currentFruitType initially to the menu... But on our site its async...

Comment: Gotcha let me fix for you.

Comment: pskink solved our issue by overriding "=="-Operator an get HashCode...